# Is there a reason not to activate/use javascript source-map in live code and packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backwards-compatibility, source-maps

When transpiling stuff to JavaScript and using source-map's:

(in four questions)

1. can we leave the `# sourceMappingURL` in production code on webpages?
2. would you run node.js applications using the `source-map-support` module in production?
3. can we use `# sourceMappingURL` in code published to npm/bower?
4. should we bundle the sources on npm?